# lxml-alternative for a BS-code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have the following code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
for elem in soup.find_all('span', 'finereader'):
    elem.replace_with(elem.string or '')
```

I'd like to use lxml, because I can't make use of the indentations which BS produces. 
Is there any equivalent code using lxml? Or how can the indentations of BS be omitted?

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Edit:
BS produces output like:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="main" frame="box" rules="all" style="table-layout:fixed; width:324.72pt; height:518.64pt;">
   <tr class="row">
    <td class="cell" style=" width:0.00pt; height:0.00pt;" valign="top">
    </td>
    <td class="cell" style=" width:169.44pt; height:0.00pt;" valign="top">
    </td>
```

But I'd like an output like:

```
<html>
<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="main" frame="box" rules="all" style="table-layout:fixed; width:324.72pt; height:518.64pt;">
<tr class="row">
<td class="cell" style=" width:0.00pt; height:0.00pt;" valign="top">
</td>
<td class="cell" style=" width:169.44pt; height:0.00pt;" valign="top">
</td>
```

EDIT:
My whole code looks like this, at the moment.

```
output = codecs.open("test.html", "a", "utf-8")

def myfunct():
    for i in range(1, 11):

        root = lxml.html.parse('http://xyz.xy'+str(nr)+'?action=source').getroot()

        for elem in root.xpath("//span[@class='finereader']"):
                text = (elem.text or "") + (elem.tail or "")
            if elem.getprevious(): # If there's a previous node
                previous = elem.getprevious()
                previous.tail = (previous.tail or "") + text # append to its tail
            else:
                 parent = elem.getparent() # Otherwise use the parent
                 parent.text = (parent.text or "") + text # and append to its text
            elem.getparent().remove(elem)

        for empty in root.xpath('//*[self::b or self::i][not(node())]'):
            empty.getparent().remove(empty)

        tables = root.cssselect('table.main') #root.xpath('//table[@class="main" and not(ancestor::table[@class="main"])]') #
        tables = root.xpath('//table[@class="main" and not(ancestor::table[@class="main"])]')

        txt = []

        txt += ([lxml.html.tostring(t, method="html", encoding="utf-8") for t in tables])

        text = "\n".join(re.sub(r'\[:[\/]?T.*?:\]', '', el) for el in txt) #.splitlines())

        output.write(text.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: What do you mean, "the indentations"? What problem are you having?

Comment: I specified the question.

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps... lxml can be finicky sometimes.

Comment: Your answer helps enormously, see the comments. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

To parse, make an `lxml.etree.HTMLParser` and use `lxml.etree.fromstring`:

```
import lxml.etree

parser = lxml.etree.HTMLParser()
html = lxml.etree.fromstring(text, parser)
```

You can now use xpath to select the things that you want:

```
for elem in html.xpath("//span[@class='finereader']"):
```

Then, since lxml doesn't let you add text nodes, and instead deals with the `text` and `tail` content of nodes, we have to do some magic to replace the nodes with strings:

```
    text = (elem.text or "") + (elem.tail or "")
    if elem.getprevious() is not None: # If there's a previous node
        previous = elem.getprevious()
        previous.tail = (previous.tail or "") + text # append to its tail
    else:
        parent = elem.getparent() # Otherwise use the parent
        parent.text = (parent.text or "") + text # and append to its text
    elem.getparent().remove(elem)
```

Then, you can use `lxml.etree.tostring(html)` to get the text back.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this code! It works partially. If I implemented the code correctly, it does remove all appearance of "<span class="finereader">". But unfortunately, if I've got something like that: "text1...<span class="finereader">some other text</span>text2...", the code above will return the following: "text1...". But I should keep (directly append) "some other texttext2...". How can this be done?

Comment: Maybe strip_tags() is a possibility?

Comment: @MarkF6 Oops, there was a typo in my code, I forgot to do the appending! Try it now. Also, are there ever going to be any tags inside of the `<span class="finereader">`?

Comment: No, if there is something, then it's only letters or numbers. I try it right now. Maaan...I should have seen the typo, too :(

Comment: The code works with 95% :). There is a special case where the code has some troubles: If I have something like this: "TEXT1 <i>TEXT2<span class="finereader">LETTER1</span> </i>TEXT3<span class="finereader">LETTER2</span> TEXT4", the code returns: "TEXT1 LETTER2 TEXT4". How can we handle such cases?

Comment: @MarkF6 Looks like there was some weirdness with `if elem.getprevious():`, it looks like it should work now. Tell me if you have any more problems!

Comment: I have one problem left: At the moment, I've got things like: "TEXT1 </b><b>TEXT2</b><span style=" letter-spacing:0.40pt;"></span></span></div>". All these "span style=" letter-spacing" should appear before the concerning text; so the result should be: "TEXT1 </b><span style=" letter-spacing:0.40pt;"><b>TEXT2</b></span></span></div>".

Comment: The above problem always appears in relation with <b>, as in the example.